# Giving Me Error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    . '/fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()'
    . '&access_token=' . $access_token;
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
$fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);

foreach ($fql_query_obj['data'] as $row) {
    echo $row['uid2'];
    echo ',';
}
```

Expected Result Is

```
xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxx,xxxx
```

It Was Working, Was Getting All Ids comma seperated
but Now It Showing error

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in xxxx.php
```

Some1 Please help

Comment: Format your question properly, please.

Comment: `print_r($fql_query_obj)` - what does this show you?

Comment: check to see if `$fql_query_obj['data']` exists.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I wanted to ask for `var_dump($fql_query_obj)`, but your option will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
foreach ($fql_query_obj['data'] as $row) {
   echo $row ;
   echo ',';

}
```

if `$fql_query_obj` is a 2D array, if its a 1D array then try

```
foreach ($fql_query_obj as $row) {
   echo $row ;
   echo ',';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a

```
var_dump($fql_query_obj['data'])
```

and look at the result to be sure your data is formatted properly.

It's most likely that facebook is returning an error or poorly formatted result. You will need to add logic to catch this, most likely, so that your foreach loop only executes once you verify that the item is an array:

```
if(!is_array($fql_query_obj['data'])){
   return false;
```

or something.